# Java read .txt file and sum the strings/int value in ASCII

Tags: java, ascii

I need **load file .txt** with strings and int.
When it is loaded, the program prints the sum of **ASCII** values that was calculated using a method (I wrote already). *My problem is sum all The strings and int*.
It necessary to sum all rows, **except** the last line that shows the sum in ASCII.

NOTICE: There is 2 groups (colors) with same info
[This the file. In yellow is the sum of all the info in .txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFQt6.png)
My code:

```js
 System.out.println("Enter Path To File:");
 File fileName = new File("Game.txt");
 Scanner sFromFile = new Scanner(fileName);
 String size = sFromFile.nextLine();
 int sizeBoard = Integer.parseInt(size);System.out.println("Board size loading size= "+size+"X"+size);
 String team = sFromFile.next();
 // int numOfSoliders = sFromFile.nextInt();
 Point arrSol []= new Point[sizeBoard];for(
 int i = 0;i<arrSol.length;i++)
 {
  arrSol[i] = new Point(sFromFile);
  System.out.println("Solider created successfully!");
 }
 // int numOfDragon = sFromFile.nextInt();
 Point arrDragon[] = new Point[sizeBoard];for(
 int i = 0;i<arrDragon.length;i++)
 {
  arrDragon[i] = new Point(sFromFile);
  System.out.println("Dragon created successfully!");
 }

 // ALSO DID THE SAME TO OTHER GROUP...

 // THE LAST LINE READING INPUT
 int fileHashCode = sFromFile.nextInt();System.out.println("HashCode loading...\n Loaded hashCode= "+fileHashCode);

 // TRY USE STRING METHOD
 // while (sFromFile.hasNext()) {
 // String str = sFromFile.nextLine();
 // System.out.print(str + ". ");
 // }

 sFromFile.close();

 // ALSO TRY OUTSIDE METHOD

 public static String readFile(String fName) throws FileNotFoundException {

  File f = new File(fName);

  Scanner sFromFile = new Scanner(f);

  for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {

   while (sFromFile.hasNext()) {

    String str= sFromFile.nextLine();
    String sum+=str;
    //  System.out.print(str + ". ");
   }
  }
  sFromFile.close();
  return sum;
 }
```

Comment: You probably know that Java doesn't use ASCII, right? (`String wink="";`) You also might know that, given the limited subset of characters the file has, you can use/abuse similarities between ASCII and UTF-16 and whatever your system default character encoding is. This is however worthy of a code comment at `new Scanner` and of future study. (It would have been easier if the supplied file was stated as using UTF-8, which is far more common.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means to sum all characters (except line breaks) of the first 7 lines of text.

*Proof*

```
String input = "8\r\n" +
               "RED\r\n" +
               "8 0 0 0 1 0 2 0 3 0 4 0 5 0 6 0 7\r\n" +
               "8 1 0 1 1 1 2 1 3 1 4 1 5 1 6 1 7\r\n" +
               "BLUE\r\n" +
               "8 7 0 7 1 7 2 7 3 7 4 7 5 7 6 7 7\r\n" +
               "8 6 0 6 1 6 2 6 3 6 4 6 5 6 6 6 7\r\n" +
               "6139";
try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(input)) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        sum += sc.nextLine().chars().sum();
    System.out.println("Calculated: " + sum);
    System.out.println("Last line : " + sc.nextLine());
}
```

*Output*

```
Calculated: 6139
Last line : 6139
```

Comment: Thanks (; Can you do ths same that sum return all String and int sum (not as int but String) From .txt Because I need the all strings in send to recursive method that do the sum of ASCIEE.

Comment: Is this will work? try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(input)) {
    String sum = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        sum += sc.nextLine().chars();
    System.out.println("Calculated: " + sum);
    System.out.println("Last line : " + sc.nextLine());
}

Comment: @linorkhbur Sorry, no idea what you're asking. The code shows how to calculate the sum that you need to compare with the number on the last line. If you want to also parse the 7 lines and load the information into data structures, you can do what while calculating the sum, or you can re-scan the file after verifying that the file is valid, i.e. the sum is correct.

Comment: Yes the sum is correct and great. But my teacher ask to sum all the strings... NOT int and send all strings to a external method I wrote... Thank you.

Comment: @linorkhbur If you only sum the ASCII characters of the "strings" (by which I assume you mean `"RED"` and `"BLUE"`), the sum will never be `6139`, since you have to sum the ASCII values of **all** the characters on the first 7 lines, including the spaces, as proven in this answer, so maybe you misunderstood what "sum all the *strings*" meant.

Comment: Thanks for all explains... I ask him and he said to take all the info in the .txt (except the last line )and make a long line of strings without the " space" that meaning of sum by him.